# SystemEvents.SessionSwitch is not fired under Windows 8.1

Tags: service

I have a small WinForms app which is using the **SessionSwitch** event to capture when a PC is locked and unlocked. When unlocked, a **MessageBox** is shown.

However, in **Windows 8**, it seems that this event is no longer fired. A suggestion on MSDN [says to create a service and use the SessionSwitch override](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4c685832-d4aa-4028-9969-60b658115736/systemeventssessionswitch-event-not-firing-in-windows-service-in-windows-7-mechine?forum=windowscompatibility). However, this is not useful for me as I want to show a message box and such cannot be shown via service. Any suggestions?